# Can't show arrayList elements in a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got the following code:
It's a class used to store a monthly summary of expenses. voci is an arraylist used to store the expenses (name and cost). mese is the month of the summary, anno the year of summary. My problem is that when I call the showRiepilogo() method i must see the list of the expenses of that month but i can't see nothing. Someone can tell me why please?

class RiepilogoMensile extends Riepilogo {

```
private ArrayList<Voce> voci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
private int mese;
private int anno;

public RiepilogoMensile(int mese, int anno, String autore, ArrayList<Voce> voci) {
    super(autore);
    this.mese = mese;
    this.anno = anno;

    // il blocco successivo è necessario???in teoria il costruttore viene invocato solo una volta.. bisogna cambiare solo la set e la get?.. provo!

    // aggiunta delle voci
    boolean voceExist = false;

    // variabile temporanea che contiene gli anni da aggiungere
    ArrayList<Voce> oldVoci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    oldVoci.addAll(this.voci);

    ArrayList<Voce> newVoci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    newVoci.addAll(voci);

    // controllo se le voci da aggiungere sono già presenti
    for (Voce a : oldVoci) {
        voceExist = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < newVoci.size(); i++) {
            if (a.equals(newVoci.get(i))) {
                voceExist = true;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if (!voceExist)
            voci.add(a);
    }

    // test costruttore
    System.out.println("Test costruttore voci--> INIZIO");
    for(Voce v:voci)
        System.out.println(v.getNome()+" "+v.getSpesa());
    System.out.println("Test costruttore voci--> FINE");
}

public ArrayList<Voce> getVoci() {
    ArrayList<Voce> temp = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    temp.addAll(this.voci);
    return (temp);
}

public void setVoci(ArrayList<Voce> voci) {
    // aggiunta delle voci
    boolean voceExist = false;

    // variabile temporanea che contiene gli anni da aggiungere
    ArrayList<Voce> oldVoci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    oldVoci.addAll(this.voci);

    ArrayList<Voce> newVoci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    newVoci.addAll(voci);

    // controllo se le voci da aggiungere sono già presenti
    for (Voce a : oldVoci) {
        voceExist = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < newVoci.size(); i++) {
            if (a.equals(newVoci.get(i))) {
                voceExist = true;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if (!voceExist)
            this.voci.add(a);
    }
}

@Override
public void showRiepilogo() {
    String messaggio = "\nRiepilogo del " + anno + " di " + Voce.intToString(mese) + " creato da " + getAutore()
            + ": ";
    System.out.println(messaggio);
    utils.showRow(messaggio.length() - 2, '-'); // tolgo 2 perchè non devo considerare \n
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Test stampa voci in showRiepilogo() voci--> INIZIO");
    // stampa voci
    for (Voce v : voci)
        System.out.println(v.getNome() + " " + v.getSpesa() + " EURO " + (v.getSpesa() > 0 ? "<--ENTRATA" : "USCITA-->"));

    for(int i=0;i<voci.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(voci.get(i).getNome() + " " + voci.get(i).getSpesa() + " EURO " + (voci.get(i).getSpesa() > 0 ? "<--ENTRATA" : "USCITA-->"));
    }

    System.out.println("Test stampa voci in showRiepilogo() voci--> FINE");

}
```

}

When I call showRiepilogo() from main i can't see nothing instead i could see the content of voci ArrayList.

riepiloghiMensili.get(index).showRiepilogo();

Someone know why?

Thanks in advice, Elias.

Comment: the post isn't clear, what is the problem, again? do you have desired input/output?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very weird constructor, you try to loop over the member this.voci but since your doing this in the constructor this.voci will always be an empty array. Look at the declaration:

```
private ArrayList<Voce> voci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
```

Your setVoci(...) method will fail for the same reason, this.voci is empty and the for loop will never be entered and no objects added to the array.

Change your constructor to just set the array to the given parameter

```
this.voci = voci
```

I would also recommend to do the same for the setVoci method or to rename it because a set... method is expected to set a member to the given parameter.

Comment: No.. Doing as what you do fails because this.voci = voci assigned the reference of the ArrayList I've tried and it doesn't works well!Doing as what you tell to do assigns the same ArrayList to all the istances of RiepilogoMensile.

Comment: You're not doing what I said, if you do "this.voci.addAll(voci);" in setVoci(...) then you shouldn't do the rest. It's either or not both. If you want to keep the rest then remove "this.voci.addAll(voci);" from the beginning of setVoci(...)

Answer (score 0):

the reference of the ArrayList I've tried and it doesn't works well!Doing as what you tell to do assigns the same ArrayList to all the istances of RiepilogoMensile.

I've done that and all works fine:

class RiepilogoMensile extends Riepilogo {

```
private ArrayList<Voce> voci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
private int mese;
private int anno;

public RiepilogoMensile(int mese, int anno, String autore, ArrayList<Voce> voci) {
    super(autore);
    this.mese = mese;
    this.anno = anno;
    this.voci.addAll(voci);
}

public ArrayList<Voce> getVoci() {
    ArrayList<Voce> temp = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    temp.addAll(this.voci);
    return (temp);
}

public void setVoci(ArrayList<Voce> voci) {
    this.voci.addAll(voci);
    // aggiunta delle voci
    boolean voceExist = false;

    // variabile temporanea che contiene gli anni da aggiungere
    ArrayList<Voce> oldVoci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    oldVoci.addAll(this.voci);

    ArrayList<Voce> newVoci = new ArrayList<Voce>();
    newVoci.addAll(voci);

    // controllo se le voci da aggiungere sono già presenti
    for (Voce a : oldVoci) {
        voceExist = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < newVoci.size(); i++) {
            if (a.equals(newVoci.get(i))) {
                voceExist = true;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if (!voceExist)
            this.voci.add(a);
    }
}
```

Thanks insted!
Bye, Elias.